# Can red dye cause premature failure in pex tubing?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I've been told that red pex had a higher failure rate because of some flaw introduced by the red dye in it. Has anyone heard anything like that? I can't find anything online about it so far.

Comment: Who has told you this? What is the increase in failure rate mentioned? If it's 10%, that could be worrying, if it's 0.01%, well, that's higher, but pretty insignificant...

Comment: I've never heard this and searching comes up empty.  It if were true I'm positive there would be a class-action suit against the manufacturers.  Lawyers are ever to enterprising about those things.

Comment: I was told by a plumber doing a bathroom. I generally work on my own plumbing but we needed this one inspected so we had to hire someone. He is definitely knowledgable about plumbing but fairly sloppy and scoffed at the notion of using red/blue to denote hot/cold saying, "That's how you know an amateur worked on it". At some point he told me that red pex had a history or failing due to the red dye or temp combined with red dye. My experience is that most things like that are just urban myths that keep getting spread but I thought I would ask around.

Comment: Yes, only amateurs color code their Pex piping because unscrupulous "professional" plumbers make it as hard as possible for anyone but the original installer to do repair work, in the hopes of drumming up more business. He probably twists the white Pex to ensure that it's as difficult as possible to follow... Sheesh.

Comment: Sounds utterly bogus. The red/blue pex I have is white pex with a thin color coat that has no function other than to color-code it - the pressure is being held by the (much thicker) white pex underneath, and there's no way the red top layer could affect that.

Comment: "...but fairly sloppy and scoffed at the notion..."  That should pretty much tell you how to take anything he says.  Good plumbers do good work.  Crappy plumbers do crappy work.

Comment: He's probably confusing tubing with [M&Ms](https://www.livescience.com/33017-why-were-red-mms-discontinued-for-a-decade.html). That was a myth, too.

Comment: Thanks all. I figured it was nonsense. He does know a lot about plumbing. I'm willing to bet that he heard the red dye thing at some point in the past, never looked into it and has been repeating it all this time as gospel. I can't tell how many times I've seen that in my real job. (which isn't plumbing most of the time) I said he's sloppy but, to be fair, I'm pretty picky about making things neat so I don't have to figure out what I did in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

It took a couple of years after this post, there is a class action lawsuit, and it explains the alleged mechanism of failure: that the process of applying the color coat involves a heat treatment which damages the pipe: https://www.classaction.org/news/discontinued-red-blue-uponor-pex-piping-plagued-by-cracking-defect-class-action-alleges